# Looping through previously detected duplicates and merging them into groups (PHP)

Tags: php

I have over 1,000,000 rows which contain some duplicates that need to be detected and grouped together.

The grouping looks something like this (in an array):

```
0 -> 4123
3 -> 344,98222
10 -> 12,333423
12 -> 756
15 -> 1,10,30400
```

What I need to do is go through this list and assign a group number to each group of duplicates. The issue here is that one key might be grouped to another, but this one is not grouped back, but grouped forward to another again. All these must be in the same group.

Using my above example, you can see that 10 is grouped to 12, 12 is grouped to 756, and 15 is grouped to 1,10 and 30400. This would mean that 10,12,333423,756,15,1,30400 all need to be in the same group!

So I need an efficient method to apply a number to all these groupings. I.e. `$group[10]=1; $group[12]=1; $group[333423]=1;` for all these, and for every grouping.

I have to find an efficient way of doing this because there are so many rows. They can only really be looped through once. I've tried doing this using brute force of checking everything but if I have to iterate through 1,000,0000 * 1,000,0000 then the script will never end as its just too many calculations.

This is all PHP and everything is in arrays. It's not in a MySQL database at this point because I don't need it to be.

Ideas?

**UPDATE**

I figured it out myself, see my answer.

Comment: Do you need to do this in PHP only or if MySql, can you please share DB schema and SQL how you retrieved initial grouping values.

Comment: It's not done with MySQL because I tried that and it was too slow. Everything is done in PHP as that's the only way I could get it to finish working everything out within a reasonable timeframe. When the results are done they'll be put back into a database.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use PHP. I don't think PHP is faster than MySQL in this kind of issue. And I think compiled language would do things a lot faster.

Comment: If you really want it done in PHP, please explain more. I don't quite understand the expected output. What is the expected structure $group for your example?

Comment: @KoalaYeung, I did it already. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
$test[0]=array(4123);
$test[3]=array(344,98222);
$test[10]=array(12,333423);
$test[12]=array(756);
$test[15]=array(1,10,30400);

$ongroup=1;
$assigned=array();
$group=array();
$idlist=array_keys($test);
foreach($idlist as $id)
    {
    if (!isset($group[$id]))
        {
        $group[$id]=$ongroup;
        $assigned[$ongroup][0]=$id;
        $ongroup++;
        }
    foreach($test[$id] as $val)
        {
        if (!isset($group[$val])) {$group[$val]=$group[$id]; $assigned[$group[$id]][]=$val;}
        else
            {
            foreach($assigned[$group[$val]] as $val2)
                {
                $group[$val2]=$group[$id];
                $assigned[$group[$id]][]=$val2;
                }
            unset($assigned[$group[$val]]);
            $group[$val]=$group[$id];
            $assigned[$group[$id]][]=$val;
            }
        }
    }

foreach($group as $id => $val)
echo $id." = $val \n";
```

Result:

```
0 = 1
4123 = 1
3 = 2
344 = 2
98222 = 2
10 = 4
12 = 4
333423 = 4
756 = 4
15 = 4
1 = 4
30400 = 4
```